# Query returns result only if element is first

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have this XML file:

```
<MyFile>
    <PossibleResponses>
        <Response text="response1"/>
        <Response text="response2"/>
    </PossibleResponses>
</MyFile>
```

I'm trying to retrieve one of the responses:

```
var selectedResponse = (from i in XElement.Load("MyFile.xml").Elements("PossibleResponses")
where i.Element("Response").Attribute("text").Value == parameter
select i.Element("Response")).Single();
```

Now if I'm trying to get the first response (parameter = response1) then it works.
If I'm trying to get the second response (parameter = response2) then it returns no result.

If I switch the order in the XML file them then response2 is returned but response 1 isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was helped by this [response](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/4294d4e0-9bcb-4980-9f9f-6f441d81f9d7)  but made some amendments:

```
var result = from i in XElement.Load("MyFile.xml").Descendants("Response")
    where i.Attribute("text").Value == "response2"
    select i;
```

According to my limited understanding of Linq, I think the key here is that ***'XElement.Load("MyFile.xml").Descendants("Response")'*** returns a list of elements so:
1. 'Where' clause  should refer directly to the element level, no need to 're-mention' its an element.
2. The same for the 'Select' clause.

Any other clarifications would be welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because in your select clause you're calling `i.Element("Response")` again, which according to the documentation returns the first element in document order (i.e response1).

Answer (score 0):

change the query to:

```
var selectedResponse = (from p in XDocument.Load("MyFile.xml") where p.Descendents("MyFile").Descendents("PossibleResponses").Descendents("Response").Any(k=>k.Attribute("text").Value == parameter) select p).Single();
```

I wrote it directly in here, so maybe there's a syntax error. the idea is to use "Descendents" method that gives you all elements with the specified name, filter element with the specific value you wish and selecting it.